# Why is my ec2 machine failing to load properly after I moved regions?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to move my host to a different region. 
I am following instructions from amazon documentation.

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html

But the "health check" fails and I cannot ssh to machine.

I am using a centos image from marketplace. I have validated that the centos image supports the region.

This is the system log I get from aws console (pasted only the end as it is too long).

How can I make this work?

```
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1423925427.781:1): initialized
HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
msgmni has been set to 1173
alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
ksign: Installing public key data
Loading keyring
- Added public key 5A35DBBA2F61C535
- User ID: CentOS (Kernel Module GPG key)
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
ipmi message handler version 39.2
IPMI System Interface driver.
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified kcs state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Could not set up I/O space
Trying to free nonexistent resource <0000000000000ca2-0000000000000ca2>
Trying to free nonexistent resource <0000000000000ca3-0000000000000ca3>
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified smic state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified smic state machine at i/o address 0xca9, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Could not set up I/O space
Trying to free nonexistent resource <0000000000000ca9-0000000000000ca9>
Trying to free nonexistent resource <0000000000000caa-0000000000000caa>
Trying to free nonexistent resource <0000000000000cab-0000000000000cab>
ipmi_si: Adding default-specified bt state machine
ipmi_si: Trying default-specified bt state machine at i/o address 0xe4, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Could not set up I/O space
Trying to free nonexistent resource <00000000000000e4-00000000000000e4>
Trying to free nonexistent resource <00000000000000e5-00000000000000e5>
Trying to free nonexistent resource <00000000000000e6-00000000000000e6>
ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Linux agpgart interface v0.103
crash memory driver: version 1.1
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input0
Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
rtc_cmos: probe of rtc_cmos failed with error -16
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 17
registered taskstats version 1
XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/vbd/2049
XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/vif/0
XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/console/0
drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
Initalizing network drop monitor service
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1280k freed
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 10240k
Freeing unused kernel memory: 796k freed
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1584k freed
dracut: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2
udev: starting version 147
dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
xlblk_init: register_blkdev major: 202 
blkfront: xvde1: barriers disabled
dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/xvde" found

dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.


dracut Warning: Signal caught!

dracut Warning: Boot has failed. To debug this issue add "rdshell" to the kernel command line.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8152812c>] ? panic+0xa7/0x16f
 [<ffffffff81077332>] ? do_exit+0x862/0x870
 [<ffffffff8118a6e5>] ? fput+0x25/0x30
 [<ffffffff81077398>] ? do_group_exit+0x58/0xd0
 [<ffffffff81077427>] ? sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
 [<ffffffff8100b072>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing this problem which is specific to RHEL 6.3 onwards and relatings to the incorrect mapping of the virtual disk - you will find some suggestions for a fix here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=255240